# java +simple Webserver +htmlform encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding, forms

As an assignment, I have ti implement a simple webserver in Java.

My Problem is:
There is a html-form that looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="dummy" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input name="in1" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="GO"/>
</form>
```

i enter >dc=mydomain.com< (without ><), press GO.

the webserver reads the post from the socket, but the parameter suddenly is 
"dc%3Dmydomain.com"

ps. i am running java 1.7.0-b147, 64bit

how can i avoid the html-form escaping characters like "=" and "," to %3D and %2C? Or make java reconstruct the original string from the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web server code you will need to use java.net.URLDecoder.decode on it. The default enctype for a form is urlencoded.

HTH

Comment: neither application/x-www-form-urlencoded, nor x-www-form-urlencoded are supported encodings (UnsupportedEncodingException), i cannot find a list of supported encodings^^

Comment: string a = URLDecoder.decode(a, "UTF-8"), not just URLDecoder.decode(a, "UTF-8")... it's late^^, thank you